# postgresql does not seem to respect the pg_hba.conf config - how can I diagnose this?

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf

I have the following pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

With the above I assume `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust` would allow TCP connections from localhost. However this does not seem to be the case

```
[root@XenonKiloCranberry:~]# psql -U postgres
psql (11.7)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \q

[root@XenonKiloCranberry:~]# psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "127.0.0.1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Where am I going wrong?

Output of `select * from pg_hba_file_rules`:

```
line_number | type  | database | user_name | address |                 netmask                 | auth_method | options | error 
-------------+-------+----------+-----------+---------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------
           1 | local | {all}    | {all}     |         |                                         | trust       |         | 
           2 | host  | {all}    | {all}     | ::1     | ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff | trust       |         | 
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Did you reload the conf files after editing?  Maybe you have multiple copies and edited the wrong (unused) one?

Comment: I restarted postgres and that didn't make any difference. Is there a way I can verify it's using the config file I expect it to use?

Comment: If you can connect by some other means (eg the local socket), you can then `select * from pg_hba_file_rules;`

Comment: And `show hba_file ; `

Comment: Thank you, that pointed me in the right direction. It seems indeed there was an alternative configuration. Feel free to post your message as an answer.

Comment: Just a tip - if you want be certain to contact a given user in comments, put `@` and their handle (normally it auto-completes) as one string - no spaces - for example, to make sure I saw something, you'd put `@Vérace` in the message body!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have restarted the database and the contents of the view `pg_hba_file_rules` doesn't match your pg_hba.conf file, then you probably have more than one such file, and edited the one which is not being used.  If you can connect via another means, you can use `show hba_file;` to get PostgreSQL to tell you which file is the one that is being used.